# JavaFX FileChooser opens at the back of a Browser

Tags: java, javafx, filechooser

I have a JavaFX application that has a button to load a file. Running JavaFX as desktop application, FileChooser window opens correctly and it appears in front of the main stage allowing me to select the desired file.

However, when I package the app to run in a browser, the FileChooser window opens at the back of the browser. Here is the Method I am using to browse for the file. how can I force that filechooser window tofront() when running the app in the browser?

```
private void loadFile() throws IOException {

        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("TXT files (*.txt)", "*.txt");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);
        File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
        filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();

    }
```

Comment: Normally, the owner window will determine over which window the FileChooser opens (or is attached to), but you are setting that to a stage in your showOpenDialog call.  So I'm guessing it just doesn't work right in a browser based environment (I haven't tried that as I don't use that kind of environment).  You might wish to file a bug report: http://bugreport.java.com